# Nested Rails Joins within Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, named-scopes

I've got 3 classes. Country, City, and Activity. A country has_many cities and a city has_many activities.

Some of the activities aren't ready yet, so the activities have an approval status. I'd like to set it up scopes, so a city without approved activities isn't valid and a country without valid cities is also invalid.

```
class ApprovalStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.approved_status_id
    ApprovalStatus.find_or_create_by(name: 'Approved').id
  end 

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Named scopes
  scope :that_is_approved, -> { where approval_status_id: ApprovalStatus.approved_status_id }

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Named scopes
  scope :that_has_valid_activities, -> { joins(:activities).merge(Activity.that_is_approved).uniq }

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Named scopes
  scope :that_has_valid_cities, -> { joins(:cities).uniq }

  # Associations
  has_many :cities, -> { that_has_valid_activities }, dependent: :destroy
```

I want the scope and the association as I want Country.that_has_valid_cities to only return the valid countries and only the valid cities to be shown within those valid countries when the active model serializer grabs the cities.

In the rails console:
City.that_has_valid _activities runs fine.

```
ApprovalStatus Load (13.4ms)  SELECT  "approval_statuses".* FROM "approval_statuses" WHERE "approval_statuses"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "Approved"]]
City Load (21.6ms) SELECT DISTINCT "cities".* FROM "cities" INNER JOIN "activities" ON "activities"."city_id" = "cities"."id" WHERE "activities"."approval_status_id" = $1  [["approval_status_id", 2]]
```

Country.that_has_valid_cities breaks.

```
ApprovalStatus Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "approval_statuses".* FROM "approval_statuses" WHERE "approval_statuses"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "Approved"]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "activities" LINE 1: ..." ON "cities"."country_id" = "countries"."id" AND "activitie...
                                                         ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "countries".* FROM "countries" INNER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."country_id" = "countries"."id" AND "activities"."approval_status_id" = $1
```

It looks like it's trying to do an AND when I want it to do a second INNER JOIN.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Named scopes
  scope :that_has_valid_cities, -> { joins(:cities).merge(City.that_has_valid_activities).uniq }

  # Associations
  has_many :cities, dependent: :destroy
```

Works and produces the queries:

```
  ApprovalStatus Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "approval_statuses".* FROM "approval_statuses" WHERE "approval_statuses"."name" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["name", "Approved"]]
  Country Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "countries".* FROM "countries" INNER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."country_id" = "countries"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "activities" ON "activities"."city_id" = "cities"."id" WHERE "activities"."approval_status_id" = $1  ORDER BY "countries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["approval_status_id", 2]]
```

However, the countries returned still list their invalid cities as the invalid cities aren't filtered from within the valid countries.

P.S. Let me know if the entire style is off here as I'm learning rails on my own.

Comment: Did you intend to really have `ApprovalStatus` as a separate model, instead of just having say an `enum status: { approved: 1 }` inside the `Activity` model?

Comment: That was an existing model when I started on the project. I should get around to fixing that though.

Comment: If a City has 2 activities: one is valid activity, the second is invalid activity, does that city still considered as valid (that it will be included in the scope `that_has_valid_activities`) ? or it only counts if both (all) activities of the city are valid?

Comment: That city would still be considered valid. I want cities with > 0 valid activities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check for the reverse. Check if there's any *activity*, *city* or *country* that's invalid. You just need to run a `find_by`. If it returns `nil`then you're golden, if it returns an object then it's invalid.

Good RoRing

Comment: That's not the behavior I want. I want any city with > 0 approved activities to appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
# app/models/approval_status.rb
class ApprovalStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities

  def self.approved_status
    # I added some caching
    return @approved_status if @approved_status
    @approved_status = ApprovalStatus.find_or_create_by(name: 'Approved')
  end
end
```

```
# app/models/activity.rb
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :approval_status

  scope :that_is_approved, -> { where approval_status: ApprovalStatus.approved_status }
end
```

```
# app/models/city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :activities

  scope :that_has_valid_activities, -> { joins(:activities).where(activities: {id: Activity.that_is_approved}) }
end
```

```
# app/models/country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities, -> { that_has_valid_activities }, dependent: :destroy
  # I added this (probably would help you along the way in case you do not know yet about :through)
  has_many :activities, through: :cities

  scope :that_has_cities_having_valid_activities, -> { joins(cities: :activities) }
end
```

### Usage

```
Country.that_has_cities_having_valid_activities
City.that_has_valid_activities
```

### Gotcha

- Take note that

  `Country.joins(:cities)` will no longer work, and will generate and Error. You'll need it always joined with `:activities` like so:
  `Country.joins(cities: :activities)`

  - This is because your `has_many :cities, -> { that_has_valid_activities }` is querying upon the associated `:activities`. Couldn't find a way to automagically make this work.

### Recommendation

- I advise not using

  ```
  has_many :cities, -> { that_has_valid_activities }
  scope :that_has_cities_having_valid_activities, -> { joins(cities: :activities) }
  ```

  but instead use:

  ```
  has_many :cities
  scope :that_has_cities_having_valid_activities, -> { joins(:cities).where(cities: {id: City.that_has_valid_activities} ) }
  ```

  - so that you can still query upon the "non-valid" cities. Otherwise, `@country.cities` will always be filtered with "valid" cities, and a possible future scenario of querying upon the "non-valid" ones will be tricky, and might involve some ugly code.
  - This will also fix the gotcha above

*Tested working*

Comment: UndefinedTable: missing FROM-clause entry for table "activities"
LINE 1: " ON "cities"."country_id" = "countries"."id" AND "activitie...

SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" INNER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."country_id" = "countries"."id" AND "activities"."id" IN (SELECT "activities"."id" FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."approval_status_id" = $1) WHERE "cities"."id" IN (SELECT "cities"."id" FROM "cities" INNER JOIN "activities" ON "activities"."city_id" = "cities"."id" WHERE "activities"."id" IN (SELECT "activities"."id" FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."approval_status_id" = $2))

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I haven't changed the approval status yet. Ran out of characters in the above comment.

  # Associations
  has_many :cities, -> { that_has_valid_activities }, dependent: :destroy 
Is key for me, but may be causing the issues.

Comment: Is that error generated when your run: `Country.that_has_cities_having_valid_activities`?